# MaterialViewPager full tab text without truncating it

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am working on an android library called [MaterialViewPager](https://github.com/florent37/MaterialViewPager)

I have five tabs, the text of some of them are little longer. I **purposely** want to show full text in tabs (finance related application). Right now the page titles are getting truncated and replaced with **...** (e.g. Exemption is being replaced with **Exe...**).

I could not find any setting that forces tab to be of full text/width.

Has anyone used this library before have achieved it? If not, is there any alternative library that can help me achieve it?

Comment: @Dipalishah - argh.. got it fixed. Silly me..

Answer (score 1):

To Force tab to show Full text try to set the `TabLayout` property `tabMode` to `scrollabale`. TabMode is having two values

```
 1. fixed   - 1
 2. scrollable   - 0
```

set it Like:

```
app:tabMode = "scrollable"
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer was simple. I just had to add a custom tab

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@id/materialviewpager_pagerTitleStrip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:pstsPaddingMiddle="true"
    app:pstsDividerPadding="20dp"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor="#FFF"
    app:pstsIndicatorHeight="2dp"
    app:pstsShouldExpand="false"
    app:pstsTabPaddingLeftRight="10dp"
    app:pstsTabTextAllCaps="true"
    tools:background="#A333"
     />
```

Notice that I set `pstsShouldExpand` to `false`. This makes sure that the tab width is not distributed, hence we can see full text.

***Note - This makes the tab width uneven.***